# how to push specific class individually into an array?

Tags: jquery, class, push, selector

```
<div class="divColorContainer">
  <div class="Blue"></div>
  <div class="Green"></div>
  <div class="Blue"></div>
</div>
```

I have a button, when clicked I want to push that attribute into a array to compare for a score function later.

I attempted `element.push($(.divColorContainer).attr(.Blue)` and many other fetch.

How do I select/push the first Blue class when the button is clicked once, then when clicked again, retrieves the next Blue class?

If you're wandering why. Its for a memory game.

Answer (score 0):

About selector you can use `$('.divColorContainer .Blue:eq('+Index+')')` to determine the element by its index using `:eq()` or `nth-child()` or using jquery `.eq()`

And I don't know which `attribute` you are talking about .. But you can use something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var Index = 0;
  $('.selectBlue').on('click',function(){
    // you can here make whatever you want 
    // for example addClass();
    $('.divColorContainer .Blue:eq('+Index+')').addClass('bg');
    Index++;
  });
});
```

```css
.bg{
  background : blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divColorContainer">
  <div class="Blue">Blue</div>
  <div class="Green">Green</div>
  <div class="Blue">Blue</div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="selectBlue">Select Blue Class</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate CSS class attribute use [special](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) jQuery methods. If you want to manipulate other attributes then use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) methods.
Use local variable and [If... Else If](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) statement to consider count of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first Stack Overflow answer, and I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but I hope I can help.

If it's a memory game, you'd probably want to keep track of which element is clicked, not just the class name, since they're reused.

Regardless, to store the class names of clicked elements to an array, you could maybe use something like:

```
var classArray = [];
$('.divColorContainer').children('div').each(function(){
    classArray.push($(this).attr('class')); // To save the class names
}):
```

To get the index of each item clicked, you could add a repeated class to each element.

Example:

```
<div class="color Blue">Blue</div>
```

Or just target them with:

```
$('divColorContainer').children('div').on('click', function({}));
```

And then set a click event to that class to get the index of the clicked element (**0 based index within its parent**). You could use something like this:

```
var colorArray = [];
$('.color').on('click', function(){
    colorArray.push($(this).index());
});
```